# Kafka & compression

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

i have 1 producer 1 consumer and 3 brokers in my set up. I am using python API for producer and consumer.

all kafka parameters are set to default meaning no compression should occur at any kafka stage.

when producer use  `"message = 'a' * message_size"`

; the network TX BW at producer is very low than i anticipate(around 50% or less than calculated BW).  when i use random (`os.random`) message i see network BW close to what i anticipate.

in both cases; when i look into message from broker side; it is read exactly as it was sent by producer.

these observation indicates that data is being compressed even-though kafka parameters are set for NO compression.

Do you know potential reason why and where compression is happening as message is sent from producer side?

I am adding code snippets as requested

---

```
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=args.kafka_broker, max_request_size=1000000000,
        batch_size=args.batch_size, linger_ms=args.linger_ms)


for i in range(element_count):
    byte_data = 'a' * send_size
    data = {'data': byte_data, 'items': send_items, 'log': 1}
    time.sleep()
    element_name = hostname
    json_aligned_data = json.dumps(data)
    producer.send(produce_topic, key=element_name, value=json_aligned_data)
```

Comment: What Kafka version (API and cluster ) ? How do you get the BW, by accessing JMX from producer ( if yes, which field exactly ) ?

Comment: Also "when i look into message from broker side" What exactly did you do?

Comment: i use kafka from https://archive.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.0.0/kafka_2.11-2.0.0.tgz ; how do i find python API version?

Comment: @MickaelMaison on broker side i actually looked into log file inside kafka logs folder

Comment: Please show use your producer code and what you saw exactly in the broker logs directory.

Comment: @MickaelMaison I have added code snippet I am using. on broker size  i used cat to look into one of segment log files and i saw 'a' repeated multiple times. (as coded in producer ocde )